# how hadoop tackles some informatica challenges

Tags: hadoop, informatica

can anyone please tell What are some of the issues with an ETL tool which are solved by Hadoop / Big data ? Why one should switch to Hadoop from informatica?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean Informatica PowerCenter. If so, you are comparing apples and oranges. PowerCenter is a data integration tool; Hadoop includes many components, but it's main purpose is big data storage and processing.

Comment: What are _some of the issues with an ETL tool_ you are referring to?